# Modifications to the default behavior in Syncfusion Blazor Grid

Tags: c#, datagrid, blazor, syncfusion

I have a grid that is working for me, but my Customer has a requirement pretty different to the default behavior. I'm now very pressed to perform this changes ASAP.

The grid has a checkbox column and multiselection is enabled. The user can select a row only through the checkboxes. For the sake of brevity, I'll copy here the settings.

```
<SfGrid @ref="Grid" DataSource="Coberturas" Width="100%"  EnablePersistence="true">
    <GridSelectionSettings Type="SelectionType.Multiple" CheckboxMode="CheckboxSelectionType.Default" CheckboxOnly="true"></GridSelectionSettings>
    <GridEditSettings AllowAdding="false" AllowDeleting="false" AllowEditing="true" AllowEditOnDblClick="false" AllowNextRowEdit="false"></GridEditSettings>
```

It has no toolbar. You can't add rows, nor deleting them. EnablePersistence is needed for reasons out of this question. There is a Primary Key column, but it is hidden (Visible is false). About the rest of the columns, they are text columns.

The customer has asked to change the default behavior in the following way:

- When the user clicks a checkbox, the row must both select and open
  for editing.
- After changing values, the edition boxes must remain
  open, even if the user press Enter or clicks another row.
- If the user clicks another row, this new row must both select and open for
  editing. Even if it's not possible to kept the previous row with the
  boxes open (I'm in doubt about if this is possible in the Syncfusion
  grid), the previous selection must be kept. All selections must not
  be lost, even if the user confirms the edition or moves to another
  row.

[Illustrative image of the requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNDSf.png)

I'm pretty new to Syncfusion controls and I have no idea how to perform this requirement. I suppose I must create handlers for some Grid Events (maybe RowSelected or OnRecordClick?) but I also may have to interrupt the default Selection and Editing behavior and I don't know how to do this. Because the pressure I have, any idea would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried talking to their support? Maybe you'll get a better and faster answer there

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this requirement by using the **RowSelected** and **OnActionComplete** events of Grid. Call the **StartEdit** method in RowSelected event handler to enable edit in a single click. And in the OnActionComplete event handler based on the RequestType as **BeginEdit** you can select the required rows based on the stored selected rows indexes  from RowSelected event handler.

Sample : https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ServerApp-614805550

Please refer the codes below,

```
<GridEvents RowSelected="RowSelected" OnActionComplete="OnActionComplete" TValue="Order"></GridEvents>

public List<double> SelectIndexes = new List<double>();
SfGrid<Order> Grid;
public bool flag { get; set; } = true;
public async Task RowSelected(RowSelectEventArgs<Order> args)
{
    if (flag)
    {
        await Grid.StartEdit();
        SelectIndexes.Add(args.RowIndex);
    }
    flag = true;
}

public async Task OnActionComplete(ActionEventArgs<Order> args)
{
    if (args.RequestType.Equals(Action.BeginEdit) && SelectIndexes.Count != 0)
    {
        flag = false;
        await Grid.SelectRows(SelectIndexes);
    }
}
```

References :
https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/datagrid/events/#onactioncomplete
https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/blazor/Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.SfGrid-1.html#Syncfusion_Blazor_Grids_SfGrid_1_StartEdit
https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/datagrid/editing/#event-trace-while-editing